# Best way of recording activity from a user in the database?

Tags: database-design, auditing

I am building an application that perform checks on users on specific days. I need to keep track of how many times these checks are performed against that particular user.

My initial thought was to just basically have a field in one of my tables which I just increment when the checks have been performed. My other thought was to create a table called "AuditUser" that will insert a new record each time the customer has been checked.

This is really a question of...**What is the best practise approach?**

If anyone else has a better solution please suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an audit table.

Then you can date partition and also archive to disk and shrink the table as needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you will only ever need a count, I would go with the field that you increment.

If you are ever going to need to do anything else, such as determine the number of times checked within a range of dates, then I would use the second table.

Comment: Yeah its really going to be used to work out billing i.e. user was checked X amount of days for the month of X. So I can see now that the table is the correct approach :)

Answer (score 0):

use the AuditUser table, you will then have a record of each check (with date+time), which is better than just a count and a last date+time.